# Programmatically reposition a UIWebView when iAD hides

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add an iAD banner to my project, and if an error occurs I will hide the banner. This cause's a blank space no naturally I wish to move the UIWebview up to fill that space. The problem is I can't seem to reposition the webview. (I am using interface builder to set the original position).

This image illustrates my layout:

[image]

Here's the code I've been trying to use to reposition which is placed in viewDidLoad:

```
//iAd
_WebsiteiADBanner.delegate = self;
[_WebsiteiADBanner setHidden:YES];

CGRect oldFrame = self.webView.frame;

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y-44, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
[self.webView setFrame:newFrame];
[self.webView reload];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You souldn't place that code in ViewDidLoad, because it only loads once. Instead you must place it in the iAd functions in it's delegates. (make sure your iAd view has set that viewController as its delegate). The following example will do it animated (haven't tested yet):

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    //hide the banner and move the webview
    [banner setHidden:FALSE];
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height);
    [self.webView setFrame:newFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    //show the banner and move the webview to the top
    [banner setHidden:TRUE];
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height);
    [self.webView setFrame:newFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly in the delegate methods as mentioned (I was just using view did load to try and invoke an immediate effect for debugging) though you accidentally missed out the size accessor in: self.webView.frame.size.width. Many thanks, this is EXACTLY what I needed.